# How to apply Eclipse Code Style to IntelliJ

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I imported Eclipse code style file in IntelliJ following steps mentioned [here](https://imagej.net/Eclipse_code_style_profiles_and_IntelliJ)

Once Java code style scheme is imported, does it automatically apply code styles to all files in your project? Or you need to do some additional stuff to apply these code styles?

I am not sure since it is not applying code styles to my Java files.

Thank You,
Prasad

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does not apply it to the source files since this would be a real big change to your codebase that should not happen automatically.

But you can update all files by selecting the src node in your project view and pressing <kbd>CMD</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> (mac) or <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>(win). This will format all files in this folder.